# Find specific elements inside array of objects and add them

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, sum

suppose we have an array of objects like this:

```
array = [{
  amount: 1000,
  cur: EUR
}, {
  amount: 1500,
  cur: GBD
}, {
  amount: 2000,
  cur: USD
}, {
  amount: 2500,
  cur: SSL
}]
```

Now I want to create a sum variable for this array which contains the sum of the amounts field whose cur isn't EUR and USD. To be more specific, I want a variable like `sumOther` which is equal to `1500 + 2500 = 4000`. This variable contains the sum of the amounts whose cur is not EUR and USD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) method

Hope this snippet will be useful

```
var sum = 0; // define a variable for adding amount
array.map(function(item){
    // check if currency is not EUR or GBD, then update the sum
    if(item.cur !=='EUR' && item.cur !=='GBD'){
    sum = sum+item.amount
    }

})
console.log(sum)
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/6jxpsdb6/2/)

Comment: If you're not using the return value from `.map()` you should be using `.forEach()`, because you're just iterating, not mapping.

Comment: @nnnnnn agree with you

Answer (score 2):

Filter, reduce, and you're done.

```
var sumOther = array
                .filter(y => y.cur != EUR && y.cur != USD)
                .reduce((a, b) => a.amount + b.amount);
```

---

< ES6 version:

```
var sumOther = array
            .filter(function(y) { return y.cur != EUR && y.cur != USD })
            .reduce(function(a, b) { return a.amount + b.amount });
```

Comment: Note that this is ES6.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but this is not correct. If i have for example three different cur except from EUR and USD this implementation didnt work

Comment: It shows me NAN if i have three different currencies and null if i have one

Comment: Can you check this fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/5e7qqzkk/ I replaced the `GBD` with `'GBD'` so it can be tested. But in my original example I used `GBD` as a variable, and not as string, just like you did in your question, that might've been the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a simple loop, testing the value of the `cur` on each iteration and adding to a total for the required values.

Or you could use the array `.filter()` and `.reduce()` methods:

```js
var array = [
  {amount: 1000, cur: 'EUR'},
  {amount: 1500, cur: 'GBD'},
  {amount: 2000, cur: 'USD'},
  {amount: 2500, cur: 'SSL'}
]

var total = array.filter(function(v) { return !/EUR|USD/.test(v.cur) })
                 .reduce(function(acc, current) { return acc + current.amount }, 0)
                 
console.log(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Example where excluded strings are not hard coded:

```js
const array = [{amount: 1000, cur: 'EUR'}, 
{amount: 1500, cur: 'GBD'}, 
{amount: 2000, cur: 'USD'}, 
{amount: 2500, cur: 'SSL'}];

const exclude = ['EUR', 'USD'];

var sum = array.map(x => (!exclude.includes(x.cur)) ? x.amount : false)
               .reduce((a, b) => a + b);

console.log(sum);
```